# How to delete a million of relationships in Neo4J Cypher without stalling the database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm making the following request:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:(1a2fbd10-7a50-11ea-bb71-25dd29c6e321)') 
yield rel 
with distinct rel 
delete rel;
```

The problem is that when I do

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:(1a2fbd10-7a50-11ea-bb71-25dd29c6e321)') 
yield rel 
with distinct rel 
return count(rel);
```

It shows that I have about 900 000 relationships.

So the first query takes too long to execute. When it's part of a transaction it stalls the database and uses too much memory.

Is there a procedure in Neo4J 3.3.9 (or 3.5) that allows me to execute this sort of long requests in batches so I don't overload my DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to take a look of `apoc.periodic.iterate` procedure which allows you to perform operations on batches of data returned by a query.
Or probably finding all required relationships wothout using APOC procedure (which is deprecated now) would be somewhat faster.

Comment: Super! This seems to have worked. I have to use APOC because all other methods are slower. My relations are indexed though using APOC, so that's why they query fast.